# Storing DataGridView data to SQL Server 2008R2?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, sql-server-2008-r2

See screenshot below...

[image: MockUp of DataGridView]

What I would like to know, what is the best way to store all data in the DataGridView to a column? This data is specific to one customer not anyone else, hence that is why I want it to store in a specific column for that customer... I use SQL Server 2008R2 and stored procedures with parameters for a head's up. If anyone could provide an example of setting this up in vb.net I would greatly appreciate it!

Here is my function that does the save except for the datagridview data...

```
     'Save the invoice to later reference it'
Public Shared Function SaveInvoice(ByVal strInvDate As String, ByVal customerID As Integer, ByVal strCustomerName As String, ByVal strHTML As String, ByVal invoiceID As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Conn As String = "Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=NuTech;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim oParam As SqlParameter() = { _
        New SqlParameter("@" & CustomerDocumentConstants.CUSTOMER_ID, customerID), _
        New SqlParameter("@" & CustomerDocumentConstants.INVOICE_DATE, strInvDate), _
        New SqlParameter("@" & CustomerDocumentConstants.CUSTOMER_NAME, strCustomerName), _
        New SqlParameter("@" & CustomerDocumentConstants.INVOICE_HTML, strHTML), _
        New SqlParameter("@" & CustomerDocumentConstants.INVOICE_ID, invoiceID), _
        New SqlParameter("@New_" & CustomerDocumentConstants.INVOICE_ID, 0)
        }

    oParam(oParam.Length - 1).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

    Try
        SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, SAVE_INVOICE, oParam)

        If oParam(oParam.Length - 1).Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            invoiceID = oParam(oParam.Length - 1).Value
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Just catch it for all I care!"
    End Try

    Return invoiceID
End Function
```

Where it says INVOICE_HTML, strHTML in my parameters: that is where I would like to use for saving the data from datagridview if possible. If you need anything to assist you please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. However, even if only one customer has a specific type of data, your database schema will need to reflect this and all the other customers will just need to have null values in that column.

Comment: Okay here is a better explanation. I have customers and I need to create invoices for them... When I go to create an invoice for them and print it, this will save in the DB for later referencing... So I will store all data associated with that invoice number... I can save everything except the datagridview data for that invoice. I am actually working with XML (writing the data to XML) and then storing this xml in my database column...

Comment: please don't show the image first because we will confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update--> I was able to get what I needed after some hair pulling with XML. I can now store and retrieve all the data that I need and it is quite fast I may say with little IO on the DB side of things. I would like to say "Thanks" for anyone that has tried to help.